# How to import an UILabel from one UIViewcontroller to another

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, textfield

I've got a problem with xcode. 
I'm a noob with object-c and xcode so... please help.

I have 2 Viewcontrollers: `ViewController (with .m/.h)` and `HighScores (with .m/.h).`

In HighScores I have put a label called first. And in `ViewController` I have a `UITextField` called *textField. I want the text in textField to be in the label when I enter the text AND when the score of the game already played is grater than the text already existing in the label ('first').

So,

This is how my **HighScore.h** looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HighScores: UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *first;

}

@end
```

and this is **ViewController.m**:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "HighScore.h"

...

NSString *myString = [HighScores.first];

if (score.text > myString) {

    NSString *string = [textField text];
    [HighScores.first setText:string]
```

but xcode says there's an error when I type "first" after the dot '.'... How can I make it if I want xCode to recognize the "first" label from HighScore `UIViewController` in `VewController` `UiViewController`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code "first" is a UILabel , it will be generated when view of highScores get loaded .
Because it is a IBOUtlet.
Secondly you are trying yo access with class name .
Make a instance of HighScore class first and than try to acess label "first".

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HighScores: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic , strong)UILabel *firstLabel  ;

@end

@implementation HighScores
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
 self.firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
 [self.view addSubview self.firstlabel];
}

@end
```

than in ViewController.m

```
HighScore * highscoreObject = [[HighScore alloc]init];

NSString *mystring = [highscoreObject.firstLabel text];

if (score.text > mystring) {

[highscoreObject.firstLabel setText:score.text];

{
```

Comment: Hmmm... how can I make an instance of the class? Could you show me with a code? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Now xCode recognizes the Label, but I have another question... I want the text in UILabel to be changed when the score is a new High Score. My code looks correct, but when I run it and play it, my UILabel doesn't change... 
I have made some edits at my code.

Comment: for your second question , it will change if the instance is same ..both controllers should be in allocated state and than pass the same instance of HighScore to the other controller and change the text of the label.. it depends on the hierarchy of your app.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! I can upvote it because I don't have 15 reputations :S but I marked it as correct!

Comment: I hope you get answer to your second question as well

Comment: I've been trying and searching.... but nothing happens :S I'm a little confused TT 
If you can help me anyway, I would appreciate it a lot :(

Comment: i think , you are at beginner's stage :( , how can we go to second controller from first controller ? navigation or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets use notification , if you are confused in here:
In this case you can also use IBoutlet.
We will throw an notification with the string to be set and read the notification in HighScores and set the label with the string send.

In ViewController.m

```
if (score.text > myString) {

NSString *string = [textField text];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"update" object:string];
}

@interface HighScores: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet  UILabel *firstLabel  ;

@end
```

and in HighScores.m

```
@implementation HighScores

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changetext:) name:@"update" object:nil]; 

}

- (void) changetext:(NSNotification *)notification {
 NSLog(@"Received"); 
   self.firstLabel.text = [notification object];
}
```

Comment: I don't know what i am doing wrong :S I am very new to the objective-c programmation....
Here there is a video of my project... If you want you can watch it for more information :(
Thanks or your effort.!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UG4xJFjfJdM&feature=youtu.be